# Drawing a Circuitikz diagram next to a table produces an hbox warning

Tags: tables, minipage, circuitikz

I'm trying to draw a Circuitikz diagram next to a table using minipages but I get an overfull hbox warning for the minipage containing the diagram, so the diagram overlaps with the table. Any ideas how to fix this? Here's what I have written along with an example:

[image]

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{circuitikz}
    
    % AND logic gates
    \node[ieeestd and port] (and1) at (0,2) {};
    \node[ieeestd and port] (and2) at (0,-2) {};

    % NOR logic gates
    \draw (and1.out) -- ++(2.5,0) node[ieeestd nor port,anchor=in 1] (nor1) {};
    \draw (and2.out) -- ++(2.5,0) node[ieeestd nor port,anchor=in 2] (nor2) {};

    \draw (nor1.in 2) -| ++ (-0.2,-0.85) -- ++(3,-1.5) coordinate(a) |- (nor2.out);
    \draw (nor2.in 1) -| ++ (-0.2,0.85) -- ++(3,1.5) |- (nor1.out);

    % Labels
    \draw (and1.in 2) -- ++(-0.75,0) node[left]{J};
    \draw (and2.in 1) -- ++(-0.75,0) node[left]{K};

    \draw (nor1.out -| a) -- ++(0.75,0) node[right]{$\mathrm{\bar Q}$};
    \draw (nor2.out -| a) -- ++(0.75,0) node[right]{$\mathrm{Q}$};

    % Additional
    \draw (and1.in 1) -- ++(0,.5)
        to (6.7,2.8) to (6.7,1.715)
    ;
    \draw (and2.in 2) -- ++(0,-.5)
        to (6.7,-2.8) to (6.7,-1.715)
    ;


  \end{circuitikz}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut JK latch truth table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      {\boldmath $\mathrm{J}$} & {\boldmath $\mathrm{K}$} & {\boldmath $\mathrm{Q_{state}}$} & \textbf{Change} \\ \hline
      0            & 0            & $Q$                  & No change       \\ \hline
      0            & 1            & 0                    & Reset           \\ \hline
      1            & 0            & 1                    & Set             \\ \hline
      1            & 1            & $\bar Q$             & Toggle          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: The circuit is too big. Add `[scale=0.6, transform shape]` to the options of the circuitikz environment, and adjust it. Or use the `adjustbox` package to squeeze it exactly to your mininpage.

Comment: @JackBrower Welcome-- please see the answer below if it suits the requirement -- the `circuitikz` length have been changed to compress it a bit --for example `and.in` has been directly labelled as `J` rather than extending it left -- similarly for the `nor.out` extension has been removed -- the crossover code between the `nor` gates has been changed for better visuals -- now there are no warnings -- the table heading has now been incorporated inside the first row of the table rather than outside the table separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain the same proportion in the diagram, and fill the line, you need the following changes:

1. two minipages of `0.5\linewidth` fill exactly the line, so you need to start with a `\noindent` (at least in standard class `article`; you didn't  provide a [full MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can't know which class you are using);
2. to align everything at the bottom, as it seems you are trying to do, you need to align *also* the table at the bottom;
3. you can reduce the very long leads in the circuit as [@js bibra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591800/38080) suggested, or you can just scale down the circuit with `scale=..., transform shape` --- that has the effect of scaling down character fonts too; if this is not wanted, you can use the "class" scale factor for the logical ports (see [`circutitz` manual](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/circuitikzmanualgit.pdf#1e)).

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\overfullrule=5pt
\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
    
    % AND logic gates
    \node[ieeestd and port] (and1) at (0,2) {};
    \node[ieeestd and port] (and2) at (0,-2) {};
    % NOR logic gates
    \draw (and1.out) -- ++(2.5,0) node[ieeestd nor port,anchor=in 1] (nor1) {};
    \draw (and2.out) -- ++(2.5,0) node[ieeestd nor port,anchor=in 2] (nor2) {};
    \draw (nor1.in 2) -| ++ (-0.2,-0.85) -- ++(3,-1.5) coordinate(a) |- (nor2.out);
    \draw (nor2.in 1) -| ++ (-0.2,0.85) -- ++(3,1.5) |- (nor1.out);
    % Labels
    \draw (and1.in 2) -- ++(-0.75,0) node[left]{J};
    \draw (and2.in 1) -- ++(-0.75,0) node[left]{K};
    \draw (nor1.out -| a) -- ++(0.75,0) node[right]{$\mathrm{\bar Q}$};
    \draw (nor2.out -| a) -- ++(0.75,0) node[right]{$\mathrm{Q}$};
    % Additional
    \draw (and1.in 1) -- ++(0,.5)
        to (6.7,2.8) to (6.7,1.715)
    ;
    \draw (and2.in 2) -- ++(0,-.5)
        to (6.7,-2.8) to (6.7,-1.715)
    ;
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    {\bfseries\strut JK latch truth table}
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|l|l|}
      \hline
      {\boldmath $\mathrm{J}$} & {\boldmath $\mathrm{K}$} & {\boldmath $\mathrm{Q_{state}}$} & \textbf{Change} \\ \hline
      0            & 0            & $Q$                  & No change       \\ \hline
      0            & 1            & 0                    & Reset           \\ \hline
      1            & 0            & 1                    & Set             \\ \hline
      1            & 1            & $\bar Q$             & Toggle          \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{circuitikz,booktabs}
\begin{document}
    {\centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{circuitikz}
            % AND logic gates
            \node[ieeestd and port] (and1) at (0,2) {};
            \node[ieeestd and port] (and2) at (0,-2) {};
            % NOR logic gates
            \draw (and1.out) -- ++(1,0) node[ieeestd nor port,anchor=in 1] (nor1) {};
            \draw (and2.out) -- ++(1,0) node[ieeestd nor port,anchor=in 2] (nor2) {};
            \draw (nor1.in 2) |- ++ (0,-0.85) -- ++(2,-1.5)|-coordinate(b) (nor2.out);
            \draw (nor2.in 1) |- ++ (0,0.85) -- ++(2,1.5) |- coordinate(a)(nor1.out);
            % Labels
            \draw (and1.in 2)  node[left]{J};
            \draw (and2.in 1) node[left]{K};
            \draw (nor1.out)  node[right]{$\mathrm{\bar Q}$};
            \draw (nor2.out) node[right]{$\mathrm{Q}$};
            % Additional
            \draw (and1.in 1)++(0.2,0) -- ++(0,.5)-|(a);
            \draw (and2.in 2)++(0.2,0) -- ++(0,-.5)-|(b);
            \end{circuitikz}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries\strut JK latch truth table}\\\midrule
            {\boldmath $\mathrm{J}$} & {\boldmath $\mathrm{K}$} & {\boldmath $\mathrm{Q_{state}}$} & \textbf{Change} \\ \midrule
            0            & 0            & $Q$                  & No change       \\ \midrule
            0            & 1            & 0                    & Reset           \\ \midrule
            1            & 0            & 1                    & Set             \\ \midrule
            1            & 1            & $\bar Q$             & Toggle          \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
     \par\vspace{0pt}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```